# Faulty partitions: Format a hard disk completely

Tags: windows, linux, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

A long story originally my Windows 8 in my ssd failed and I try to install ubuntu but unfortunately the installation is disrupted.  I end up installing centos on my disk. Now I just want to install windwos 8 back to my disk. But the windows installer said the disk is locked and I see there are no partition suitable for installation.
I view from centos that the major space is taken up by a disk with format lvm2... I

I don't mind erasing the centos or whatsoever. I just want to be able to install windows back, just like when I start with a fresh new ssd drive. Hope someone can help!

Comment: Can you delete the locked partition or does windows just not see your disk at all?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Ubuntu CD, select 'Try Ubuntu' and then from inside Ubuntu start GParted. There you can delete all the partitions. After that, Windows should be able to see it as unpartitioned space.

Windows tends not to see UNIX file systems.